# laravel documentación de baconQRCode

Tags: laravel, documentacion

Estoy buscando la documentación oficial del paquete baconQRCode para Laravel, y no la encuentro en ninguna parte, ni en foros, ni nada. Alguien puede darme una URL donde esté dicponible?

Comment: existen librerias que no cuentan con una pagina oficial, puede que sea uno de ellos, yo mismo tengo montado algunas librerias con una explicación básica. Tus opciones serian buscar una nueva libreria, o mejor creas la tuya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación oficial la tienes [aquí](https://github.com/Bacon/BaconQrCode).

Simplemente debes instalarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
composer require bacon/bacon-qr-code
```

Debes tener en cuenta que debes tener instalado **imagick**. Si estás trabajando en windows, [aquí](https://tektriks.com/a-step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-install-imagemagick-in-windows/) te dejo un tutorial sobre cómo hacerlo.

Teniendo instaladas ambas cosas, es sencillo lo demás. En la documentación te dan el siguiente ejemplo el cual haré en `web.php`.

`web.php`

```
<?
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\ImageRenderer;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\ImagickImageBackEnd;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\RendererStyle\RendererStyle;
use BaconQrCode\Writer;

Route::get('/', function(){
   $renderer = new ImageRenderer(
       new RendererStyle(400),
       new ImagickImageBackEnd()
   );
   $writer = new Writer($renderer);
   // Se guarda la imagen en 'public/' con el texto que quieras
   $writer->writeFile('Hello World!', 'qrcode.png');

   $rutaImagen = 'qrcode.png'; // Toma desde /public
   return view('welcome', compact('rutaImagen'));
});
```

En tu vista `welcome.blade.php`:

```
<div class="content">
     <img src="{{ $rutaImagen}}" alt="">
     <div class="title m-b-md">
        Laravel
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracis por tu aprtación. La "documentación" de ese github la ví, pero es extermadamente escueta. No describe cada clase, ni los métodos que implementa, ni practicamente nada. No sabrás de algo un poco más detallado? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Dicho paquete es práctico, sirve para generar códigos QR, para qué necesitas una documentación tan extensa? En todo caso, entra al link GitHub que te dejé y navega por las clases y métodos que tiene y verás toda la lógica que hay, no es mucho código.